# A better way to do this search and replace for a template

Tags: php, replace

I currently do search and replace for a web page template like this:

```
$template = <<<TEMP
<html>
<head>
<title>[{pageTitle}]</title>
</head>
[{menuA}]
[{menuB}]
[{bodyContent}]
</html>
<<<TEMP;
```

**The above is placed in a separate file.**

**Then, I do:**

```
$template = str_replace("[{pageTitle}]",$pageTitle,$template);
$template = str_replace("[{menuA}]",$menuA,$template);
$template = str_replace("[{menuB}]",$menuB,$template);
$template = str_replace("[{bodyContent}]",$bodyContent,$template);
//Some 10 more similar to the above go here.
echo $template;
```

The problem is, there are some 15 in total just like the ones above.

Is there a better/cleaner/professional way to do this (either the search and replace, or do the entire thing differently). I find this very messy and unprofessional.

Comment: Cleaner? Try take a look at [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/). It is a PHP template engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can define array of things you want to replace and another array with things to replace with.

```
$array1 = array("[{pageTitle}]", "[{menuA}]");
$array2 = array($pageTitle, $menuA);

$template = str_replace($array1 , $array2 , $template);
```

Answer (score 2):

By modifying [ljubiccica's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16214132/739897). You can create associative array with variables and values and then replace them:

```
$array=array(
        'pageTitle'=>$pageTitle,
        'menuA'=> $menuA,
        );

$addBrackets = function($a)
{
    return '[{'.$a.'}]';
};
$array1 = array_keys($array);
$array1 = array_map($addBrackets,$array1);

$array2 = array_values($array);

$template = str_replace($array1 , $array2 , $template);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use an existing library like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) or [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

If you want to roll your own templating solution you could use regular expressions:

```
// Just an example array
$values = array('pageTitle' => 'foo', 'menuA' => 'bar');
$offset = 0;
while(preg_match('/\[\{([a-zA-Z]+)\]\}/', $template, $matches, 
  PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset)) {
    $varname = $matches[0][3];
    $value = isset($values[$varname]) ? $values[$varname] : "Not found!";
    $template = str_replace('[{'.$varname.'}]', $value, $template);
    $offset = $matches[1];
}
```

If you don't like associative arrays, you can do this instead:

```
$value = isset($$varname)? $$varname : "Not found";
```

But I'd advise against that because it could expose variable you don't want to be exposed.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use existing template engines. I suggest [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), because it's simple and fast!

Answer (score 0):

what about using a regular expression. something like the below:

```
   $matches = array();
    preg_match_all("/\[\{.*?\}\]/", $template, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[0] as $match){
    // this will replace the '[{','}]' braces as we don't want these in our file name
    $var = str_replace("[{", "", $match);
    $var = str_replace("}]", "", $var);
    // this should pull in the file name and continue the output
    $template = str_replace($match, $$var, $template);
    }
```

I haven't tested it but this way you wouldn't have to know what you need to replace? It would replace what's in your [{text}] tags with $text for example?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that something like this actually works:

```
    $foo = 'bar';
    $baz = 'foo';

    $test = 'Test [{foo}] and [{baz}]';

    $test1 = preg_replace("/\[{(.*?)}\]/e", "$$1", $test);
    $test2 = preg_replace_callback("/\[{(.*?)}\]/", function($v) use($foo, $baz)
            {
                return ${$v[1]};
            }, $test);
    var_dump($test1); //string 'Test bar and foo' (length=16)
    var_dump($test2); //string 'Test bar and foo' (length=16)
```

So in your case:

```
$template= preg_replace("/\[{(.*?)}\]/e", "$$1", $template);
```

**Edit:**

You can also chekck if the variable is set like this:

```
    $foo = 'bar';
    $baz = 'foo';

    $test = 'Test [{foo}] and [{baz}] or [{ble}]';

    $test1 = preg_replace("/\[{(.*?)}\]/e", "isset($$1) ? $$1 : '$$1';", $test);
    var_dump($test1); //string 'Test bar and foo or $ble' (length=24)
```